# How to connect to adhoc wifi on Nokia XL

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, ad-hoc-networks, nokia-xl

Is there a way I can connect Nokia XL phone to adhoc wifi created using my laptop.
I've had Nokia 900 which connected & Nokia N8 connects to the same wifi hotspot while none of Samsung (Android) devices do.

How about Android powered Nokia XL? Please share your experience if you have a workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wonder if the *Nokia XL* makes an exception here – but as you can find out by other questions tagged [ad-hoc](/questions/tagged/ad-hoc) and our [ad-hoc tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ad-hoc-networks/info), Android itself doesn't support this type of networks by default. Usually, solutions involving this require [root](/questions/tagged/root) access on the device (which again does not ship by default) – and [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting) in most areas voids your device's warranty.